Confusion about deriving possible minimal polynomials given characteristic polynomial
Let $A\in \mathbb{F}^{3\times 3}$ whose characteristic polynomial is $\chi_A(x)=-x(x^2+1)$. Find all possible minimal polynomials of $A$ for the cases $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ and $ \mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}.$
Attempt. For $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$, since $\chi_A(x)=-x(x-i)(x+i)$, the only
possible minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x(x-i)(x+i)$. For $ \mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$,
since  $m_A(x)$   divides $\chi_A(x)$ and share the same roots on $\mathbb{R}$, the only
possible minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m_A(x)=x$ ie $A=\mathbb{O}$, a contradiction (since $\chi_\mathbb{O}(x)=-x^3$).
Obviously, in the real case, there some flaw in the above argument, which I can't find.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Are you saying $A^2+I=0$? Because I don't think that is true.

You are right, I mixed it with the $2\times 2$ case.

We are left with the real case of question 2.

This question is similar to: Does the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial have same roots over F, for a linear operator on vectorspace V over the field F?, found using MSE's search engine: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=minimal+polynomial+and+characteristic+polynomial+over+R. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You might also use the search engine of MSE to find similar posts.

For $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$,
since $m_A(X)$ divides $\chi_A(X)$
and share the same roots in $\mathbb{R}$, which are $\sigma_{\mathbb{R}}(A)=\{0\}$,
we have two possible choices:
$$m_A(X) = X
\quad \text{or} \quad
m'_A(X) = X(X^2+1).$$
For the first possibility,
we obtain
$A = m_A(A) = 0 \in \mathcal{M}_{3,3}(\mathbb{F})$.
Thus $\chi_A(X)=X^3$,
which is a contradiction: $m_A(X)=X$ cannot be a minimal polynomial.
For the second possibility, I will exhibit
$A' = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.
Then,
$\begin{align}
A'(A'^2+I_3)
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\left (
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\right ) \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 0
\in \mathcal{M}_{3,3}(\mathbb F).
\end{align}$
In conclusion, for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ must be $m'_A(X) = X(X^2+1)$.
